# Find Expiry Date in MVC .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 months plan and payment date is 21-08-2017(mm/dd/yyyy) how to find Expiry date according to 3 months plan

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Is `DateTime.AddMonths(3)` what you're looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add three months to the payment date :

```
var expiryDate = paymentDate.AddMonths(3);
```

Comment: it's take automatic month like feb,march, april.....like that acoording to months days

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. That method just adds months to the date, keeping the day when possible. Just try it yourself.